# how to solve creating database file error in redhat linux

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, redhat, sqlplus, oracle12c

I have sql scripts in folder in the location
/root/Desktop/artifacts_2019-06-03_234105/db-core

as

```
[oracle@ol7-122 ~]$ cd /root/Desktop/artifacts_2019-06-03_234105/db-core
[oracle@ol7-122 db-core]$ ll
total 5436
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root    3007 Jun  3 23:41 10_DBA_CreateEnv.sql
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root    1102 Jun  3 23:41 15_DBA_CreateBLOBTablespace.sql
```

when I'm trying to execute from oracle system user , there is an error in creating database file in the location : /root/Desktop/RSA

like

```
SQL> @10_DBA_CreateEnv.sql;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

CREATE TABLESPACE RSACOREDATA DATAFILE '/root/Desktop/RSA' SIZE 1024M REUSE AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 100M
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01119: error in creating database file '/root/Desktop/RSA'
ORA-27056: could not delete file
Linux-x86_64 Error: 21: Is a directory
```

I don't know what to do.

can anyone help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
create tablespace ... reuse
```

means that you'd want to ... well, *reuse* existing file. You said that `/root/Desktop/RSA` is to be reused:

- Oracle then complains that it can not delete file

  - in *valid* circumstances, you'd have to take the tablespace offline first
- Linux says: `Is a directory`

From my point of view, it seems that you are reusing a *directory* instead of a *file*. If that's so, specify file name, not directory name.